# Insert mode counts in neovim

Tags: key-bindings, neovim, count

Is there  a way  to get insert  mode emacs  style meta
counts in neovim (which has support for the meta key)?

Such that, for instance, `<m-3>-` produces 3 hyphens.

PS. I mean  is it possible  to produce the  exact same
behaviour.   In this  case,  `<m-3>-`  is better  than
`<esc>3a-<esc>a`.

Answer (score 6):

Yep. `{count}i{text}<esc>`.

For example: `80i-<esc>` will insert 80 equal signs. Great as a markdown horizontal rule.

And mappable in your `~/.vimrc`

```
nnoremap <Leader>hr 80i-<esc>
```

**Reference**

`:help insert`

Comment: I knew that `i` took a count, but it never occurred to me that I could actually use it for something useful.  Thanks!  It should be noted that this is repeatable using `.`, in which case, it may be better to use `80a-<esc>` to keep the cursor at the end of the inserted text.

Comment: Nice. I like `a` even more! I almost always want my cursor at the end a change (like every other non-vim-editor).